# Are covering indexes also sorted on the included values?

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following table:

```sql
create table bar.foo (
  a bigint not null,
  b bigint not null,
  value bigint not null,
  primary key (a, b)
);
```

And the following initialization code:

```sql
do $$
begin
  for r in 1..10000000 loop
    insert into bar.foo (a, b, value) values(1, r, r);
  end loop;
end;
$$;

create index schema_name_foo_a on bar.foo(a) INCLUDE (b, value);

vacuum (analyse , verbose)  bar.foo;
```

The index `schema_name_foo_a` has a common prefix `1`.  According to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html), The included values are only used in the leaf B-tree nodes.   This seems to imply that Postgres would need to do a full scan of the nodes that have a common prefix to find the element that I am looking for.   To be specific:

```
explain (verbose, analyse , buffers ) select a, b, value from bar.foo where a = 1 and b = 5000000;
Index Scan using foo_pkey on bar.foo  (cost=0.43..8.46 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=1.714..1.717 rows=1 loops=1)
"  Output: a, b, value"
  Index Cond: ((foo.a = 1) AND (foo.b = 5000000))
  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=3
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=29
Planning Time: 0.344 ms
Execution Time: 1.776 ms
```

My question is: Are covering indexes with common prefixes slow to read from and update?  If not, does this imply the included columns are part of the key used in the B-tree nodes?

Comment: "*The index `schema_name_foo_b` has a common prefix `1`.*" - no, the index is on the `b` column, which has 10000000 different values

Comment: Oops, you are correct, I adjusted the index, but the overall question still stands.

Comment: Well now the execution plan show that Postgres does *not* use the `schema_name_foo_a` index any more, because it won't be specific enough. It chooses the `foo_pkey` index created from the `primary key (a, b)`. if you remove that primary key from your test case, you'll probably see a full table scan, or a rather slow index scan.

Comment: Even with the pkey index, It seems like updates should be slower.  For example:


explain (analyse , verbose, buffers ) update bar.foo set value = 66 where a = 1 and b = 5000000;

It doesn't seem possible that schema_name_foo_a could be updated efficiently.

Comment: Ah now I get the question, you're asking how the `include`d values get `update`d in a btree index when there's lots of entries with the same key

Comment: I don't believe that that query will get that plan - there cannot be an index scan on `b`. Indexes are not sorted by or searched for `INCLUDE`d columns.

Comment: Does that mean the index `schema_name_foo_a ` won't be updated until the next vacuum?